# I am not able to print the value of object using Generic class

Tags: java, android

What i am doing..

1. create a modal class with two attribute or respective getter and setter.
   code:

```java
public class Employee {
    private int eid;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int eid, String name) {
        this.eid = eid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getEid() {
        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

2. Creating Generic class who have one methos of generic type see below.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

public class TableName<T> {

    public void addTableData(List<T> t) {

        if (t.size() > 0) {
            Class c = t.get(0).getClass();
            Field[] f1 = c.getDeclaredFields();
            for (T t1 : t) {
                Class<T> tClass = (Class<T>) t1;
                for (Field field : f1) {
                    String name = field.getName();
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. I am calling the method of TableName and want to print attribute value.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   

        TableName<Employee> table = new TableName<Employee>();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();       
        list.add(new Employee(1, "Pankaj"));
        list.add(new Employee(2, "Gupta"));
        list.add(new Employee(3, "kumar"));
        list.add(new Employee(4, "pintu"));
        list.add(new Employee(5, "rinku"));
        list.add(new Employee(6, "tinku"));

        table.addTableData(list);
    }
}
```

I have to print the value of object like 1, pankaj 2 gupta etc or respective getter setter also.

Thanks.

Comment: What is  System.out.println(name); printing in the logcat??

Comment: it's print variable name eid & name

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use reflection you should able to obtain field values like this:

```java
public void addTableData(List<T> list) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (T item : list) {
        Class c = item.getClass();
        Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        StringBuilder itemRepr = new StringBuilder();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String name = field.getName();
            Object value = field.get(item);
            itemRepr.append(name).append('=').append(value).append(", ");
        }
        if (itemRepr.length() > 0) {
            itemRepr.setLength(itemRepr.length() - 2);
        }
        System.out.println(c.getSimpleName() + "{" + itemRepr + '}');
    }
}
```

But that solution is very expensive. Why just not to override `toString()` in `Employee` class?

```java
class Employee {
    // some code here ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{name=" + this.name + ", eid=" + this.eid + "}";
    }
}
```

And then just print employees using

```java
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: did but still not able to print the value.Exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Employee.name to java.lang.String    Thanks .

Comment: if (t.size() > 0) {
            Class c = t.get(0).getClass();
            Field[] f1 = c.getDeclaredFields();
            for (T t1 : t) {
                Object obj = (Object) t1;
                for (Field field : f1) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String name = field.getName();
                    Object value = field.get(obj);
                    Object value1 = field.get(name);
                    System.out.println(name + " " + value);
                    System.out.println(name + " " + value1);
                }
            }

Comment: @pankajgupta I've also made some pretty print in `addTableData` so you can also check it :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to override toString() method and set required fields there and call Object.toString() wherever you want to print the values

Comment: I did and value is displaying But i want each value should be retrive using getter & setter. Because using toString() i am only able to print one value either name or id

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method in your class

```
   public class Employee {
    private int eid;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int eid, String name) {
        this.eid = eid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getEid() {
        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Assuming only name needs to be printed
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And in you can print it like

```
Employee emp = new Employee(1, "Pankaj")
System.out.println(emp);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any way to access the value using getter and setter. Without overiding the method toString(). Thanks